# How to make a slanted vertical bar?

Tags: characters, italic, slanted

I'm stumped on this.  I would like to make a slanted (and italic) vertical bar in the middle of some regular text.

If I use `$|$`, it comes out literally vertical regardless of style, since it's a math operator.

For reasons I don't understand, `|` is accepted by TeX but comes out as an em-dash rather than a vertical bar.

Using `\char124` works fine for the typewriter font, but I need this for Computer Modern Roman Slant & Italic.

I only need this so that I can see the exact slope of slanted and italic text visually; it's temporary for lining some things up.  I can get by for now with `[` and `]`—which do display correctly in slanted and italic shapes—but now I've become very curious about how to make the vertical bar work, because I don't like it when I don't understand things. :)

Comment: Use T1 font encoding to get the vertical bar in text mode: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` allows you to use `|` in normal text, and `\textit{|}` allows you to see the slanted version. However if you are visually lining things up, you should think again. There are better way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use T1 font encoding for that, as the default OT1 encoding doesn't support the vertical bar in text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\textit{Text | Text}

\textsl{Text | Text}
\end{document}
```

[image: italic and slanted vertical bar]

Comment: Aha!! I *thought* I had that working at one point long ago. I was beginning to wonder if I'd gone insane. This is the problem (for me) with constructing new macros inside a simplified environment instead of inside the normal templates I use. Thanks, Stefan!